# Disable today's date after certain time

Tags: jquery, shopify, jquery-ui-datepicker, liquid

I'm a bit new to coding but i've added a datepicker to my website. Now I want to close off today's day after 10 am in the datepicker. Any help would be much appreciated. The code that I have so far is:

```
$(document).ready( function() {  
$(function() {
var holiDays =[[2017,05,14,"Mother's Day"],[2017,09,3,"Father's Day"],[2017,04,14,"Good/Easter Friday"]];
$("#date").datepicker( {
  minDate: +1,
  maxDate: '+6M',
  dateFormat: "dd/mm/yy",
  beforeShowDay: setHoliDays
} );
  // set holidays function which is configured in beforeShowDay
 function setHoliDays(date) {
 for (i = 0; i < holiDays.length; i++) {
 if (date.getFullYear() == holiDays[i][0]
      && date.getMonth() == holiDays[i][1] - 1
      && date.getDate() == holiDays[i][2]) {
    return [true, 'holiday', holiDays[i][3]];
 }
}
// return [true, ''];
var weekenddate = $.datepicker.noWeekends(date);
return weekenddate; 
\}
});
})
```

Comment: It is not clear what you are asking for; it kinda sounds like you want help on a feature as a whole but we are lacking context. StackOverflow questions should ideally be more focused than that as well, with a clear problem that you're trying to solve and only the code that is required for others to answer your question. Try to clarify your question, and edit out unrelated parts of the code as necessary :)

Comment: Sorry about that. I'm kinda new to this. What I basically want is to disable the ability to pick today's day after 10 am, because that is the close off time for people to order for same day delivery.

Answer (score 0):

Read carefully the [api](http://api.jqueryui.com/datepicker/).

you can change minDate on the fly, test the date and if is after 10 am use this:

```
$('#date').datepicker('option', 'minDate', new Date(newDate));
```